# get current timestamp in a speciific form HH:MM:SS.XXXX+05:30

Tags: python, time

I want to get the current time in the form of `14:42:49.901013+05:30` in python. Can anyone help me how can I do this?

Comment: Use [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime).

Comment: @Selcuk The question does not ask about ignoring the TZ.

Comment: @LutzHorn Yes, the question I linked is about _adding_ timezone to a naive datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
tz_now = datetime.now(tz)

print tz_now

>>> 2016-04-08 14:11:00.648000+05:30
```

You can convert it to string and split it to get time with timezone